# iphone 4 links create red semi transparent background/overlay on touch :active

Tags: javascript, iphone, css, ios, iphone-4

I seem to be having a problem on the mobile version of a site in iphone 4 where when a link is selected a semi transparent red box is overlayed kind of like the outline in ff etc except the full area is red, I thought this could just be an iphone 4 thing but when I checked the bbc website they have a grey overlay so this must be able to be controlled.

I have tried adding background to the :active state in css but this doesnt seem to work, has anyone any ideas what can be done to alter this?

Regards
Kyle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watch the `-webkit-tap-highlight-color:` CSS property. You can define it to `rgba(0,0,0,0);` if you want to avoid the effect, or tweak it as you want.

Also, read the [official doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/AdjustingtheTextSize/AdjustingtheTextSize.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006510-SW1) for more info.